# Next.js tutorial, error running Next.js dev server (npm run dev)

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

I'm doing the [starter Next.js tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/foundations/from-react-to-nextjs/getting-started-with-nextjs) and encountering an error when I try to run the Next dev server and run my app.

Here is what my package.json file contains:

```
{
  "scripts": {
      "dev": "next dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^12.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

When running `npm run dev`, I get the following error:

```
> @ dev /Users/renaudj/Documents/Projects/next-app
> next dev

/Users/renaudj/Documents/Projects/next-app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/report/index.js:14
    reporters = [];
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/renaudj/.npm/_logs/2022-07-04T05_09_15_196Z-debug.log
```

Anyone know what I'm missing here? Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing your Node version is less than 12.0. See [Minimum Node.js version](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#minimum-nodejs-version), you need at least 12.22.0

Comment: Thanks, Phil. That was the issue.

Comment: That means that this docs page is wrong because it says minimum node version is 10.13 - https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup

Answer (score 8):

I update my node version V11.15.1 to V12.22.1 then it's solved

Answer (score 0):

I update my node version V10->V16. it' work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, updating your version of node will solve this issue.

Before doing this, delete the *node_modules* folder in your project.

Then to update node to the latest stable version, run the following command on your terminal:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

You may need to restart your terminal to see the version update which you check using:

```
node -v
```

Then reinstall your project using

```
npm install
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Basically I have multiple versins of node.
2. It is possible through **nvm**
3. I switched to node 14 using the command :

   node use 14.15.0